# Pass a list to Image src

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I send a `List` in a `ViewBag` to a `View` that has to pass this list as a parameter to a function, but I can't get that list in my function.

Here's the code:

```
 @{ 
         List<Statistic> i = ViewBag.list ;
  }

 <img src="/Chart/CreateChart?chartType=@(System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column)&list=@i" alt="" />
```

So, please help me out.

Comment: Please take a look at the Help>Tour (button in the top right corner) of StackOverflow and posting comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it in to that type:

```
@{ 
         var i = ViewBag.list as  List<Statistic>;

 }
```

or:

```
@{ 
             var i = (List<Statistic>)ViewBag.list;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Assign the Value to the `Image src` Do Like Below.

Your Value Assignments are not proper to the Image src.

```
<img src="/Chart/CreateChart?chartType=" + @(System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column) + "&list=" + @i alt="" />
```

We can't assign a class to the `img src` straight away. It will never compiled in Html. Do you have any other `Js/Cs` library compilations at your end?

Comment: the object Statistic contains two properties X and Y and i need the hole list to create my chart

Comment: @soumia See my updated answer. And post your Answer as a comment here. Since its not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: it's not working,the problem is not in the way i pass the parameters,because if i change the type of list into string ,i'm able to get the value in my function ,but when it comes to list it doesn't work

Comment: ok. what is that value? If you want to use the list you need to loop and get the each value from the list one by one and assign it. You will get each value in your function. you can't assign list straight away to the `image src`.  If you don't want to loop you have to do some thing else. what is your function? where you are calling the function here?

Comment: thanks  a lot RJK,I solved the problem by performing a serialization of  my list before i put it in the src  ,and then I deserialize it when i get it back  in my function

Comment: You are welcome soumia. Just put your answer here will help some one in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by performing a serialization of my list before i put it in the src ,and then I deserialize it when i get it back in my function like below :

first in my controller i serialize of my list

```
 string jsonString = JsonHelper.JsonSerializer<IList<Statistic>>(list);

        ViewBag.list =jsonString;
```

and in my action createchart i deserialize my list :

```
IList<Statistic> lists = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<IList<Statistic>>(list);
```

and this is JsonHelper class:

```
 public class JsonHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// JSON Serialization
    /// </summary>
    public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
        string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        return jsonString;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// JSON Deserialization
    /// </summary>
    public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
```